# Can the PrimeFaces rowExpansion animation be controlled / disabled?

Tags: jquery, animation, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

In PrimeFaces (I'm using 4.0) you are able to have a [`dataTable` with expandable rows](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableExpandableRows.jsf). Basically you have a `p:rowToggler` button which toggles the `p:rowExpansion`. This works fine, but I really hate the fade animation on the row expansion content, which makes the toggling feel sluggish (especially when closing a row expansion).

Is there any way to control / disable the fade animation? It doesn't seem there are attributes on `p:rowToggler` or `p:rowExpansion` to control this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row expansion is handled by the Javascript code at:

```
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources/primefaces/primefaces.js
```

at the line starting with:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable
```

If you reformat the code it will be readable.

There is one usage of [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and one of [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). Both don't take an options object, so configuring it is out of the question.

You could do a hack to disable the animation by:

1. copying the file from `primefaces-x.x.jar` at `META-INF/resources/primefaces/primefaces.js` to your project and
2. replacing

   1. `fadeIn(` with `fadeIn(0`, and
   2. `fadeOut(function(` with `fadeOut(0,function(`

   on the line starting with `PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable` and, most important,
3. repeat this process each time you upgrade PrimeFaces :(

I've created an issue for this at PrimeFaces.
See https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6775

---

### Update

I just received a [response on issue 6775](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6775#c1):

> Due to issues like [7380](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7380), we had to disable animation.